# Erro ao compilar Dagger 2 no Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, injeção-de-dependência

Estou estudando o exemplo de projeto do site oficial do Dagger, que pode ser acessado neste link: https://github.com/google/dagger/tree/master/examples/simple/src/main/java/coffee. Estou utilizando a IDE eclipse. Quando executo o projeto ele dá erro na linha onde é feita referência à classe gerada Dagger_Coffee. O Eclipse simplesmente não está gerando este arquivo automaticamente, como afirmam os tutoriais. Saliento que não vou utilizar o Dagger em um projeto mobile, mas sim com Java EE. Sei que CDI é o mais adequado, mas este é um requisito do meu patrão. O que deve estar havendo de errado?  Segue o código:

```
package coffee;

import dagger.Component;
import javax.inject.Singleton;

public class CoffeeApp {
@Singleton
@Component(modules = { DripCoffeeModule.class })
    public interface Coffee {
        CoffeeMaker maker();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
      Coffee coffee = Dagger_Coffee.builder().build();
      coffee.maker().brew();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

O Dagger não gera mais classes com "_" , portanto substitua `Dagger_Coffee` por `DaggerCoffee` e em seguida dê um *Rebuild* no projeto.